# Django on Webfaction: Serving static admin media files - configuration

Tags: django, static, django-admin

I having trouble serving Django's static admin files on webfaction.

Here's how I'm currently set up:

- I've created a 'Symbolic link to
  static-only app', and provided the
  link to Django admin files in 'extra
  info':
  `/home/myusername/webapps/mydjangoapp/lib/python2.5/django/contrib/admin/media`
  (cd'ing into that directory works
  fine)
- I've added this app to my django
  website, and specified `/media` as the
  URL path.
- In my django settings,
  `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'` (my
  static files are prefixed with
  /static/, so there's no conflict
  here)

  In the source code of an admin page,
  I can see that admin media is
  correctly linked, e.g. `<link
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="/media/css/base.css" />`

However, following the link I get a 404 page (from nginx).

I've played around with this forever now, so any ideas what might be wrong here, or any recommendations on how to troubleshoot this would be really appreciated!

Comment: I eventually opened a ticket with webfaction, turn out the setup I described above is correct, but that when I created the static app, i specified the path without the leading slash, which is something you cannot change later - so the static app was removed and reinstalled with the correct path, and all is working now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a trailing slash on the "Symbol link to static-only app", it should be:

```
/home/myusername/webapps/mydjangoapp/lib/python2.5/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

(or at least, that's what works for me at Webfaction).

If that doesn't work - ask them, they've got really the most helpful support team of any hosting company I've used ever.

Answer (score 1):

In your second point URL path entry would be `/media/admin` as you can see in [webfaction-docs](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django.html#serving-admin-media).

Their support is really good when you open a ticket or post a question in their django [forums](http://forum.webfaction.com/) :)